# No receiver reports generated on RTP multicast via vlc

Tags: vlc, wireshark, rtsp, rtp, rtcp

I have been trying to stream via RTP and RTSP using vlc. The strange thing is that when streaming is done via RTSP (unicast), RTCP generates both Sender Reports and Receiver Reports, but when streaming is done via RTP multicast only Sender Reports are generated. The clients are not generating any Receiver Reports. I use wireshark for packet sniffing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Currently none as such. I am simply using the GUI for VLC and wireshark.